# Tailwindcss background image not showing on deploy

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

Both the background image and navbar background don't render. I'm using Vercel and Netlify to deploy and have used the build command as well as the publish directory setup on both sites. Tried checking my code since I'm using Tailwind for the first time, but I still can't figure out what went wrong?
The repo: https://github.com/d4nky/Tailwindcss-Portfolio 
The site: https://inspiring-carson-2c8f1d.netlify.app

Any piece of information would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `img` directory in your dist too, because for now, you are using path `/img/background.jpg` which refers to repo `/dist/img/background.jpg` file, that doesn't exist.

You can check that in the console, which says:

```
GET https://inspiring-carson-2c8f1d.netlify.app/img/background.jpg [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
```

And the same for `logo_size.jpg`.

You could put those directories directly to dist directory by hand, or use some bundling tool like webpack to automate things.

Answer (score 1):

Because the site can't find the resources.
[image]

The links you specified in index.html are relative ones, the absolute path of which are `path/to/index/` + `value/of/src`. For example your page will actually look for the main.js in `repo-root/dist/dist/`.

So you should either properly store and link your resources, or learn to use bundle tech, e.g. webpack.